# Math.pow calculations ground and power

Tags: javascript, math, pow

I want to create a piece of code with `Math.pow`

For instance, if I put as a ground number 2 and power level 6
I want the result to count from 0 to 6.

> 2^0 = 1
>   2^1 = 2
>   2^2 = 4
>   2^3 = 8
>   2^4 = 16
>   2^5 = 32
>   2^6 = 64

This is what I currently have: [(on JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/g4maC)

```
function callPow(){
    var val= document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var power= document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    alert(Math.pow(val,power));
}
```

Comment: this is what i currently have http://jsfiddle.net/g4maC/

Comment: thank you for your response yes the code works but i want the output to count from 0 to the power level what i put in and display it

Answer (score 4):

All you need is a loop that will count up to your specified power and alert each time:

```
function callPow(){
    var val= document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var power= document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    for(i=0; i<= power; i++){
        alert(val+' ^ '+i+' = '+Math.pow(val,i));
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4maC/5)

Answer (score 3):

A simple `for` loop should suffice.

Something like this

```
function callPow(){
    var val= document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var power= document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    for(count=0; count<= power; count++){
           alert(val + "^"+ count+"="+Math.pow(val,count));
    }
}
```

Also here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4maC/6/)

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you may also do it using a `while` loop

```
function callPow(){
    var val= document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var power= document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    var count=0;//as you want to start from power 0
    while ( count<= power){
           alert(val + "^"+ count++ +"="+Math.pow(val,count));

    }
}
```

Fiddle for this will be http://jsfiddle.net/g4maC/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
<script>
 function callPow(){
   var val= document.getElementById("txt").value;
   var power= document.getElementById("txt2").value;
     for(var i=0; i<=power; i++)
     {
    alert(Math.pow(val,i));
     }
 }
 </script>
   Input number :<input type="text" id="txt" value=""/>
    to the power<input type="text" id="txt2" value=""/>
  <button onclick="callPow();">Show Value</button>
```